# How to use graph api to post comments

Tags: php, facebook, json, facebook-graph-api

If I have 10 friends how do i get the latest status for each of them and then post a comment on all of these statuses?

how do you get the post ID?

```
  $facebook->api('/'.$POST_ID.'/comments','post',array('message' => $comment));
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't find a way to get friends statuses ordered by date from the Graph API, so you'll have to use FQL. This query will get you the 10 most recent status updates by your friends:

```
SELECT uid,status_id,time,message FROM status WHERE uid IN 
    (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) ORDER BY time DESC limit 10
```

There is no guarantee that these 10 will come from different friends since there is no way to execute a `UNIQUE` query in FQL. If you want to ensure you're commenting on 10 unique friends' statuses, you'll have to request more results and keep track of whose posts you're commenting on in your script.

From here, you can loop through these results and set `$POST_ID = $result['status_id']` then execute your API call above.

If this is for a public app you're building, you'll want to look at combining these 10 updates together into a single batch.request to keep from running into the API call limits.